# Point pattern classification with spatstat: how to choose the right bandwidth for the kernel density?

Tags: classification, gis, spatstat

I'm trying to find the best way to classify bivariate point patterns in `spatstat` according to the relationship between two point species:

[Point pattern classification with spatstat: what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67298342/point-pattern-classification-with-spatstat-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

[Point pattern classification with spatstat: how to choose the right bandwidth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68401868/point-pattern-classification-with-spatstat-how-to-choose-the-right-bandwidth)

I used @Adrian's suggestion from the first link.

```
  Cancer <- split(cells)[["tumor"]]
  Immune <- split(cells)[["bcell"]]
  Dimmune <- density(Immune,sigma=bw.diggle)
  f <- rhohat(Cancer, Dimmune)
```

`f` is a "resource selection function" (RSF) which describes the relationship between the intensity of the Cancer point process and the covariate (here kernel density of Immune with with `sigma=bw.diggle` as I wanted an automatic bandwidth selection).
After extracting the values of `f` I ran a hierarchical clustering or K-means on the values.

I am in doubt about some results I've got. A dozen of rho-functions looked weird (disrupted, single peak). After changing to default `sigma=NULL` or `sigma=bw.scott` (which are smoother) the functions became "better" (see examples below). I also experimented with running the RSF-calculation for patterns with randomly re-assigned marks, or for simulated segregated and clustered patterns in the same window and with the same number of points as the originals (examples below).

I first used `bw.diggle` for the kernel density calculation, because `hopskel.test` indicated "clustering" for all my patterns. Now I'm going to use `bw.scott` for my analysis but can this decision be somehow justified? Is there a better method besides "RSF-function is looking weird"?

some examples:

sample10:
[image: sample10 bw.diggle vs bw.scott]
sample20:
[image: sample20 bw.diggle vs bw.scott]
sample110:
[image: sample110 bw.diggle vs bw.scott]